# ExtentReports doesn't save the screenshot with the report

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, test-report, screenshot, extent

Hello I am trying to capture screenshot of failed test cases using selenium webdriver with Maven and TestNG with following code, it does generate the screenshot in my project but doesn't get included inside the report what do I need to change in the code?

```
 WebDriver driver;
ExtentReports extent;
ExtentTest logger;
@BeforeTest
public void setUp() {
    extent = new ExtentReports("C:\\Users\\IdeaProjects\\p\\test-output\\report.html", true);
    extent.loadConfig(new File("C:\\Users\\IdeaProjects\\p\\test-output\\extent-config.xml"));
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
}
@Test
public void testExtentReports() {
    logger = extent.startTest("testExtentReports");
    Assert.assertTrue(false);
}
@AfterMethod
public void tearDown(ITestResult result) throws IOException {
    if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
        logger.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Test Case Failed is "+result.getName());
        logger.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Test Case Failed is "+result.getThrowable());
        String screenshotPath = TestMine.getScreenshot(driver, result.getName());
        logger.log(LogStatus.FAIL, logger.addScreenCapture(screenshotPath));
    } else if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SKIP) {
        logger.log(LogStatus.SKIP, "Test Case Skipped is "+result.getName());
    }
    extent.endTest(logger);
}
public static String getScreenshot(WebDriver driver, String screenshotName) throws IOException {
    String dateName = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss").format(new Date());
    TakesScreenshot ts = (TakesScreenshot) driver;
    File source = ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    // after execution, you could see a folder "FailedTestsScreenshots" under src folder
    String destination = "ss/" + screenshotName+dateName+".png";
    File finalDestination = new File(destination);
    FileUtils.copyFile(source, finalDestination);
    return destination;
}
@AfterTest
public void endReport() {
    extent.flush();
    extent.close();
    driver.quit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are correctly capturing the screenshot in the method `getScreenshot` and appending the screenshot path to the `ExtentReports` logger object.

However, the issue is that you are saving the screenshot in your project directory (`ss/`) instead of inside the ExtentReports HTML report.

You can resolve this issue by changing the destination of your screenshot file. Instead of saving it in the project directory, you can save it inside the `ExtentReports` HTML report using the following code:

```
String destination = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\test-output\\Screenshots\\" + screenshotName + dateName + ".png";
```

This will save the screenshot in the Screenshots folder inside the test-output folder of your project.